# How to reset the AutoGenerated Key in JPA in case of rollback?

Tags: java, jpa

I have a situation where i need to reset the auto-Increment key to the previous value in case of roll back. I have a series of create statement in my controller class. If any exception occurs I am able to roll back all the create statements. But the the auto-Increment generated doesn't reset for a particular successfully entity. Kindly help

**The following is my contoller class.**

```
@EJB
private jpa.session.ClassMasterFacade ejbFacadeCM;
@EJB
private jpa.session.StudentMasterFacade ejbFacadeSM;
@EJB
private jpa.session.ParentsMasterFacade ejbFacadePM;
@EJB
private jpa.session.AddressMasterFacade ejbFacadeAM;
@Resource
    UserTransaction tran;
public String confirmData() {
    try {
    tran.begin();
        ejbFacadeSM;.create(selectedSM);
        ejbFacadeCM;.create(selectedCM)
        ejbFacadeAM;.create(selectedAM);
        ejbFacadePM;.create(selectedPM);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tran.rollback();
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle ("/resources/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        return null;
    }
 }
```

**Example Facade Class**

```
@Stateless
public class ClassMasterFacade extends AbstractFacade<ClassMaster> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "sdjv_smsPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public ClassMasterFacade() {
        super(ClassMaster.class);
    }

}
```

All other facade classes are similar to the above class. The abstract class is:

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

    public void create(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
    }

    public T find(Object id) {
        return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
    }
}
```

The **autogenerated key** in each enityclass is similar to

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "class_group_id")
private Integer classGroupId;
```

Comment: You will probably wont be able to do that with build-in JPA mechanisms. The point of AI for particular table is to provide uniqueness for all entities accross all transactions done simultaniously. So for example if you would runt 2 similar transactions at once, and one would succeed, from the point of view of one of them AI would have new value, and old value from the rollbacked one. This would cause uniqueness violation in any transaction that would come onwards because AI counter would be set to some already used value. This is not done on JPA side, but on DB side

Comment: @ Antoniossss  totally agreed with what you say. Can you suggest the way ahead? I mean i can stop worrying about this but i wanted a continuous AI.

Comment: Simply, you cannot have guaranteed that AI columns (specially the ones that are to be unique) will be persisted in order without gaps, just because of what I have wrote - rollbacks. You would have to manually set those values in serialized transactions but IDK is it worth of work.

Comment: You should add the DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ...). But in general this is not how auto generated values work. Their ***only*** purpose is to be unique. You can never assume that they are gapless (and you can't really assume that they are increasing as well, some implementations allow for a later transaction to get a _lower_ value that a previous transaction). And no DBMS I know can actually roll back the generated value - which is one of the reason why they are fast **and** scalable **and** safe to use with concurrent transactions.

Comment: DBMS is mysql. I understand the use of auto generated key . I understand now that what i was looking for is not possible. Generating my own sequence is  not also feasible. Perhaps i will stop worrying about it and leave it there. Thank you all for your thoughts!!!